# How can I draw a interaction plot using trimmed means?

Tags: r, interaction, ggplot2, trimmed-mean

I am conducting two-way ANOVA in r using the t2way function in WRS2 packages for my thesis.

t2way function, as you know, uses trimmed mean to escape from the severe problem of heterogeneity of variance.

but the problem is, I don't know how to draw an interaction plot using trimmed means.
I've tried to use a basic interaction plot function, but it probably doesn't have any options for trimmed mean.

can I use ggplot2 packages for it? Does it have any options for it? or there is some syntax for it?? I have definitely no idea anymore

and I am not **native English user** so tell me if you don't understand my intention. It would be my fault.

Comment: Couldn't you just compute all the trimmed means involved and then construct all the elements of the plot manually how you want them?

Comment: thank you for comment! so you mean, I compute all the trimmed means individually for each cell, and making the plot with those only trimmed mean values? I didn't know it works for ggplot!! thank you I will try!